# Is this grammar L4 ambiguous?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, ambiguity

S-> AAB|ABA|BAA|epsilon

A->aS

B->bS

this is a grammar of the language L4 = {w ∈ Σ*: #a(w) = 2#b(w)} over Σ = {a, b}

Does the following examples shows that the L4 is ambiguous?

S->AAB->aSAB->aAB->aaSbS->aab

S->AAB->aSaSbS->aab

I'm not sure if these derivations are the same,
if they are not, what are the derivations that shows the ambiguity of L4?

Comment: Welcome to CS StackExchange!  What are the pound signs (#) in your equation?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of ambiguous?  Where did you get stuck?  Have you tried searching this site?  There are *lots* of questions here that explain the notion of ambiguity in grammars; you should study them, then try to solve your question again.